# What is incorrect about this Elasticsearch OR Query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to OR together two clauses in a single query but I am seeing some strange behavior and am looking for guidance

Given an index "index1" with two documents -

```
{"column1": "A"} with _id=1
{"column1": "B"} with _id=2
```

When run a POST index1/_search with following body -

```
{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "should": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"term": {"_id": "1"}},
                        {"term": {"column1": "A"}}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"term": {"_id": "2"}},
                        {"term": {"column1": "B"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}}
```

I get no results.   What I was expecting was both documents to be returned. If I remove one of the column1 term matches,  I will get the other document.  If I remove both column1 term matches, I get both documents?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I were to write this in SQL - SELECT * FROM index1 WHERE (_id=1 AND column1 = "A") OR (_id=2 AND column1 = "B")

Comment: data type of column1 is keyword

Comment: What is the mapping type of `column1`? Pretty sure it's `text`... do you have `column1.keyword`?

Comment: @BobLukens did u get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Val already suggested, you should have used `column1.keword`, if you are taking default mapping of `column1`

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_id": "1"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "column1.keyword": "A"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_id": "2"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "column1.keyword": "B"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "fd_cb",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "column1": "A"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fd_cb",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "column1": "B"
        }
      }
    ]
```

If you have already defined explicit mapping for `column1`, like the one shown below :

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "column1": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then the search query, mentioned in your question works perfectly fine.